# Windows 2008 BITS Server

Tags: iis, bit

Attempting to get BITS running on IIS 7 (Server 2008)

Everything installs fine, I setup a virtual directory, all relevant permissions, etc.

When I do this, it breaks my existing website and I can replicate the problem.

If I click "BITS Uploads" on the Virtual Directory, allow clients to upload files with customize settings, then Apply and Run cleanup, the settings don't stick.  It's inheriting from the main server settings.  If I change BITS Uploads there in the main server settings, then my website dies with a 500 error.

Anybody an expert with BITS or have an alternative way of uploading or downloading in a trickle type fashion?  (no rsync, etc)  Would rather keep it all .NET (which I'm using SharpBITS project implemented code).

"C:\Windows\System32\bitssrv.dll"  (this is supposedly the correct ISAPI dll also)

Zack

Comment: Try creating a separate site as opposed to default web site, and put it on a separate application pool. This way your existing site isn't adversely affected.

Comment: That's exactly what I had to do, so I just created another APP Pool and made sure "Enable 32-bit" is FALSE - that seems to work, but I doing it that way and assigning it to the existing site (even converting to an application) didn't seem to work either.  So I just gave it other port number and will have to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a separate Web Site Web Application, and put it on a separate application pool. This way your existing site isn't adversely affected.